# Как засунуть все приложения в одну папку apps?

Tags: python, django, app

Я хочу заснуть все свои приложения в одну папку apps

НО я не нашел нормального ответа.

Я пробовал

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))
```

и

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join('BASE_DIR', 'apps'))
```

и

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Insert the two lines below
APPS_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '<your_project_dir_name>/apps/')
sys.path.insert(0, APPS_DIR)
```

и

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../apps'))
```

и везде я прописывал `__init__.py`

результат одинаковый

Единственное что я смог это просто написать в

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'apps.myapp',
]
```

Но такой способ кране нежелательный

Comment: Django в принципе не очень хорошо работает с подобными засовываниями

Comment: зачем это нужно ?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю проблема в том как ты вызываешь приложения в списке INSTALLED_APPS=[]
То что ты написал в первом варианте правильно:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))
```

PROJECT_ROOT это наша корневая папка проекта, где settings.py, wsgi.py и др. И мы добавляем туда еще одну папку **apps**. Попробуй в INSTALLED_APPS добавлять приложения способом '<app_name>.apps.<app_name>Config'. Как пример приложение 'landing_page':

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'landing_page.apps.LandingPageConfig',
]
```

[image: Как должно выглядеть]

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с версии Django 3.1+ авторы перешли с **os.path** на **pathlib**
поэтому **BASE_DIR** и **PROJECT_ROOT** теперь выглядят так:

```py
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    PROJECT_ROOT = Path(__file__).parent
```

Если вы хотите хранить все ваши приложения в проекте в одной папке (допустим **my_apps**), то вам необходимо это указать следующим образом:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(str(PROJECT_ROOT / 'my_apps'))
```

обращаю внимание на то, что теперь это не строка. Теперь это <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'> Поэтому необходимо выполнить приведение к типу '*string*'

В данном примере **PROJECT_ROOT** ссылается на уровень где находится **settings.py**. Если вам необходимо чтобы ваша папка была на уровне **manage.py**, то тогда:

```py
PROJECT_ROOT = Path(__file__).parent.parent
```

`__init.py__` ни где прописывать не надо

ваши приложения (допустим **one_app**, **two_app**) нужно просто указать так:

```python
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'one_app',
    'two_app',
]
```